# Get data in row format

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to get data from the table:

```
id | parametername | value | datetime
```

as:

```
               parametername1 | parametername2 | patametername 3

     datetime1 value            value            value
     datetime2 value            value            value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select datetime,
       max(case when parametername = 'name1' then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when parametername = 'name2' then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when parametername = 'name3' then value end) as value_3
from t
group by datetime;
```

Comment: Hi! And I took advantage of this solution, but I can have up to 150 parametername, make the request not so big will not work?

Comment: @Dmitry . . . It will work for 150 parameters.  You can use a spreadsheet (or SQL query on metadata tables) to generate the code.